# How fix the Drools' error using Eclipse?

Tags: drools

In my Java code I wrote:

```
KnowledgeBaseConfiguration config = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBaseConfiguration();
config.setOption(EventProcessingMode.STREAM);
```

And the *setOption* method, Eclipse throws the following error:

**Bound mismatch: The generic method setOption(T) of type KnowledgeBaseOptionsConfiguration is not applicable for the arguments (RuleBaseConfiguration.EventProcessingMode). The inferred type RuleBaseConfiguration.EventProcessingMode is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter *< T extends KnowledgeBaseOption >***

Answer (score 1):

According to some 5.x Javadoc:

```
 config.setOption(EventProcessingOption.STREAM);
```

Where is `...Mode...` coming from?

Comment: Writing **config.setOption(EventProcessingMode.STREAM);** Eclipse throws the same error, I don't know to do...

Comment: It should be EventProcessing`Option`.STREAM, and if you really changed that, the error message can't be the same. Drools Version? Please post complete code to reproduce the problem - shouldn't be more that 15 lines... And is the Eclipse setup for Drools correct?

Comment: laune thank you for your answer. My Drools version is **drools-distribution-6.0.1.Final**. The Eclipse setup for Drools is correct because I have wrote some rules and java code without any problem

Comment: Well, as I wrote, don't use EventProcessing*Mode*. - If you have changed this to the correct name (see answer) and still get an error, what is the text of the *new* error?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `EventProcessingOption` instead of `EventProcessingMode` in your java code as given in [tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.2.0.CR1/drools-fusion-docs/html/ch02.html):

```
KnowledgeBaseConfiguration config = KnowledgeBaseFactory.newKnowledgeBaseConfiguration();
config.setOption(EventProcessingOption.STREAM);
```

EventProcessingMode is used in drools configuration in xml. i.e.

```
<drools:kbase id="kbase">
  <drools:resources>
    <drools:resource  type="DRL" source="classpath:drools/rules.drl" />
  </drools:resources>
  <drools:configuration>
    <drools:mbeans enabled="true" />
    <drools:event-processing-mode mode="STREAM" />
    <drools:assert-behavior mode="EQUALITY" />
  </drools:configuration>
</drools:kbase>
<drools:ksession id="ksession" type="stateful" name="ksession" kbase="kbase" />
```

Refer the [example](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.drools/drools-spring/5.2.1.Final/org/drools/container/spring/session-conf-beans.xml).